# Using Apple MDM, I can't get ByPass Activation Code

Tags: mdm, apple-developer

Is it possible to create Bypass Code for macOS 10.15+ devices without DEP? The machine is on macOS 10.15.7. The enrollment is a self-installed MDM profile.

I prefer to get the ByPass Code with the help of Apple MDM.

Note, when I upgraded the macOS to 13.2 Ventura, this command ActivationLockBypassCodeCommand can get back the bypass code. But on the page [get_the_bypass_code_for_activation_lock](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/get_the_bypass_code_for_activation_lock), it mentioned the minimum supported version is macOS 10.15+

- [activation_lock_a_device](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/activation_lock_a_device)
- [creating_and_using_bypass_codes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/device_assignment/activation_lock_a_device/creating_and_using_bypass_codes)
- [get_the_bypass_code_for_activation_lock](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/get_the_bypass_code_for_activation_lock)

Answer (score 0):

Requesting that code from a device requires that it’s supervised, so your description appears to be an expected response. Supervision (as a title) for computers was introduced in macOS 10.15, but in that release only applied to computers that were enrolled via Automated Device Enrollment. In macOS 11+ that all expanded, where any user-approved MDM enrollment was considered supervised, which would explain how it worked after upgrading.